# How to Directly show price from Customization option in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, custom

While creating customization product we usually add the extra charge required than the base charge. 
Lets say Mobile Case= 100, Extra Printing Charge= 20. So we write 20 in the Customization option.

My requirement is that I will write 120 directly in the customization option. Means it will show the amount written in the Option, not adding it with the base.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik it is not possible to do it while you configure the configurable product options, but you should be able to change the simple product price once all the products are created. So you add `0` for everything and save, once all the simple products are created, directly add your price in the price attribute of the simple product.